# How to run ansible from a GCE Instance from GCP Project A to manges hundreds of VMs in GCP Project B,C,D (no shared VPCs)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, continuous-integration, google-compute-engine, google-vpc

I have a VM (VCE Instance) in GCP (Google Cloud) in Project A (Let's call this "ansible_vm"), where I have my Ansible playbooks and inventories.

I also have hundreds on VCE Instances in multiple projects (B,C,D etc).

There are no Shared VPCs amongst these GCP projects.

Is there way I can run ansible and ansible-playbook commands from the "ansible_vm" to manage the VMs in GCP Projects B,C,D etc? One problem I can see already is that I have no way to ssh from "ansible_vm" to the other VMs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can move VMs between projects ([link](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-move-a-vm-instance-between-projects-on-google-cloud-platform-39d1690c73a)), but since you have hundreds of instances, that's not viable.
Which leaves you with two options:

1. Use [Shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc), and designate **Project A** as the ***host project*** and attach other projects as ***service projects***.
2. Use [VPC Network Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering).  This, however, has a relatively low [limit](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota#vpc-peering) of 25 networks.